# nested mapping in Spring Boot does not load static content

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, uuid, get-request

So it's my html file:

getPass.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="../static/image/PUB_PIX_LION_K.jpg"
          th:href="@{image/PUB_PIX_LION_K.jpg}">
    <link href="../static/css/style.css"  th:href="@{css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <title>PP-Secure</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper-notification">

    <h3>Password:</h3>
    <p th:text="${dispPass}"></p>
    <p th:text="${dispError}"></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it is my Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("password/link/{enterId}")
    public ModelAndView getPasswordById(@PathVariable("enterId") UUID uuid) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        if(passwordService.hasKey(uuid)) {
            String passText = passwordService.getPassTextById(uuid).getPassText();
            mv.addObject("dispPass",passText);
            mv.setViewName("getPass");
        } else {
            String error = "No password available.";
            mv.addObject("dispError",error);
            mv.setViewName("getPass");
        }

        passwordService.removePasswordAfterVisit(uuid);

        return mv;
    }
```

The problem is when i use this URL (the Argument of the above @RequestMapping() ) the html page use neither of .css (styling) and the .jpg (logo in browser tab) so i tried everything and finally wrote a test mapping :

```
    @GetMapping("test")
    public String showGetPass(){
        return "getPass";
    }
```

And everything is ok with localhost:8080/test , i mean the logo appears in browser tab and the styling is there from .css

So my fast solution was that i packed all my .css file in `<style></style>` tag in getPass.html ... but i was curious to know:

Is there any problem to have UUID as endpoint of a URL for a Get Request? I mean, does it make a problem for linking the css file in html file?

UPDATE:
It is working when i removed `password/link/` in `@RequestMapping`but what is wrong with xzy/jkj/{id} ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

the only thing i needed was a `/`!!!! behind the css : `th:href="@{css/style.css}"` so `th:href="@{/css/style.css}"`

Why on earth it makes difference between `@GetMapping("xxx")`and `@GetMapping("nested/xxx")`... !!!!